# Jstl equals doesn't work

Tags: jstl

The jstl equals method doesn't work for me for some reason. The code is

```
<span>${fromerror}</span>
<span>${fromerror eq 'mandatoryCriteria.criteria.from'}</span>
```

yet the result is like this

```
 mandatoryCriteria.criteria.from    
 false
```

I'm using jstl 1.2

More specifically I'd need it in if statement but the result is the same

```
<c:if test="${not empty fromerror and fromerror eq 'mandatoryCriteria.criteria.from'}">
```

Comment: fromerror probably has leading and or trailing white spaces.

Comment: Can I know the reason for downvote please?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. The problem was that fromerror variable actually contained something like this

```
<span id="from.errors">mandatoryCriteria.criteria.from</span>
```

Which browser evaluated as "mandatoryCriteria.criteria.from". And that's why eq didn't work